# How to cook Brussells Sprouts and sweet potates in one oven?

Tags: vegetables

I need to roast the Brussels sprouts at 350 for 40" and bake the sweet potatoes at 425 for 60" in one oven.  How should I do it?

Comment: Neither should be put into an oven. Both respond better to steaming, and then, optionally, searing of sweet potatoes. They both have delicate tastes and textures, which are easily ruined if overcooked. Precise timed steaming is the way to go

Comment: I prefer sautee for brussels sprouts, personally. Pass on the sweet potatoes :S

Comment: Roasted sprouts? Why? Would you roast a cabbage?

Comment: Roasted Brussels sprouts are fantastic, everyone needs to chill with this inquisition

Comment: Ooh. I had some roaster sprouts a couple of days ago. Brilliant. I withdraw my earlier sentiment.

Answer (score 4):

I have this problem frequently of needing to cook different things at the different temperatures in the oven at the same time. I tend to get around it by choosing the average temperature of the two (in your case ~390F) and adjust my cooking times appropriately. At 390F, I would cook for roughly the following times for your foods:

Brussels Sprouts    35"
Sweet Potatoes      70"

They should could in a pretty similar manner to your recipe, but I'd keep an eye on them to ensure they come out perfect.

Hope that helps!

Mike

Comment: Also, assuming you will be using the top rack position and the lower-middle rack position (?), I would recommend reversing AND rotating the pans after 20 minutes (or so) to insure even heating around the pans and from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I've done almost exactly this many times. Your oven may differ from mine (hot spots, small, large, etc.)

I cut sprouts in half north to south, trim the tough part of stems, toss the sprouts lightly in some oil, spread them on a baking sheet of some kind, sometimes toss the sliced bacon pieces on top. Oven at 400. Some will brown a bit, which is my goal. Test them around 30 minutes. After they're done, I finish with kosher salt, pepper and sometimes lemon juice.

Baking sweet potatoes bare; not foil wrapped? Medium sized unwrapped potatoes *may* be done around 45 minutes (test with toothpick).

If you're committed to the 425 degree temp, delay putting the sprouts in (let the potatoes get a head start), then test the sprouts every 15 minutes, and toss them on the sheet, then another 15,etc. After they start to brown, you could lay some foil on top of them to allow time to cook the interior more.

If you're looking for a non-roasted sprout type of result, cover them with foil the entire cooking time and still check them every 15 minutes, otherwise, use steam.

I also vote for trading the foods between the racks and rotating the two sheets, but that's because my oven is small enough that this matters.

Good eating!